# can use neither and not together?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

The price estimates include both state and national taxes, neither not delivery charges.

Is this corrected?

I know 'neither' and 'not' can't use together.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. It should be

- The price estimates include both state and national taxes, **but** not delivery charges.

(by the way, you didn't say which country. If this were in America, we would say "federal" rather than "national", and might say "shipping" rather than "delivery".)

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense to me only as:

*The price estimates [**do**] include state and national taxes, **but not** delivery charges.*

Translated:

YES YES NO [in terms of inclusions]

or, with a different meaning:

*The price estimates **do not** include state and national taxes, **nor** delivery charges.*

NO NO NO

or, with the same meaning as the latter:

*The price estimates **do not** include state and national taxes. **Neither do they include** delivery charges.*

NO NO NO

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! I easily understand that by your answer.